# Azure CLI hangs when deleting blobs

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I'm using the Azure CLI to delete multiple blobs (in this case there's only 3 to delete), by specifying a pattern:

```
az storage blob delete-batch --connection-string myAzureBlobConnectionString -s my-container --pattern clients/client_name/*
```

This hangs and sees to get stuck in some kind of loop, I've tried adding --debug onto the end and it appears to be entering a never ending cycle of requests:

```
x-ms-client-request-id:16144555-a87c-11e9-bf86-sd391bc3b6f9
x-ms-date:Wed, 17 Jul 2019 10:17:12 GMT
x-ms-version:2018-11-09
/fsonss7393djamxomaa/mycontainer
comp:list
marker:2!152!XJJ4HDHKANnmLWUIWUDCN75DSDS89DXNNAKNK3NNINI4NKLNXLNLA88NSAMOXA
yOCE5OTk5LTEyLTMxVDIzOjU5OjU5Ljk5OTk5OTlaIQ--
restype:container
azure.multiapi.storage.v2018_11_09.common.storageclient : Client-Request-ID=446db2f0-d87e-11e9-ac19-jj324kc3b6f9 Outgoin
g request: Method=GET, Path=/mycontainer, Query={'restype': 'container', 'comp': 'list', 'prefix': None, 'delimiter
': None, 'marker': '2!152!MDAwMDY4IWNsaXASADYnJpc3RvbG9sZHZpYyOKD87986xlcy8wYWY3YTllYi02MzUyLTRmMmUtODE3MaSDXXZTdkYmYzOT
cuanBnITAwMDAyOCE5DADATEyLTMxVDIzOjUDD8223HKjk5OTk5OTlaIQ--', 'maxresults': None, 'include': None, 'timeout': None}, Head
ers={'x-ms-version': '2018-11-09', 'User-Agent': 'Azure-Storage/2.0.0-2.0.1 (Python CPython 3.6.6; Windows 2008ServerR2)
 AZURECLI/2.0.68', 'x-ms-client-request-id': '1664324-a87c-1fsfs-bf86-ee291b5252f9', 'x-ms-date': 'Wed, 17 Jul 2019 10:1
9:14 GMT', 'Authorization': 'REDACTED'}.
urllib3.connectionpool : https://fsonss7393djamxomaa.blob.core.windows.net:443 "GET /mycontainer?restype=contain
er&comp=list&marker=2%21452%21MDXAXMDY4IWNsaWVudHMvYnJpc3RvbG9sZHZpYySnsns8sWY3YTllYi02MzUyLTRDASXXDE3MS01YzJmZTdkYm
YzOTcuanBnFFSFSAyOXASAOTk5LTEyLTMxGSGSOjU4535Ljk5OTk5OTlaIQ-- HTTP/1.1" 200 None
azure.multiapi.storage.v2018_11_09.common.storageclient : Client-Request-ID=544db2f0-a88c-23x9-ac19-jkjd89bc3b6f9 Receivi
ng Response: Server-Timestamp=Wed, 17 Jul 2019 10:19:14 GMT, Server-Request-ID=44fsfs2-701e-004e-2589-3cae723232000, HTT
P Status Code=200, Message=OK, Headers={'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'content-type': 'application/xml', 'server': 'Wi
ndows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0', 'x-ms-request-id': '4a43c59b2-701e-44c-2989-3cdsd70000000', 'x-ms-version':
'2018-11-09', 'date': 'Wed, 17 Jul 2019 10:19:14 GMT'}.
azure.multiapi.storage.v2018_11_09.common._auth : String_to_sign=GET
```

It loops these requests over and over. Running an az storage list with a prefix returns the 3 files immediately.

Any ideas?

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a minor error in your cli code: the container name is incorrect(means it does not have the path `clients/client_name`).

In your cli code, the container name is `my-container`. But in the debug info, I can see the container name is `mycontainer` which is not consistent with the name in your cli code.

Please make sure you specify the correct container name in your cli code, and which does contain the path `clients/client_name`.

I test the code at my side with a container, which does not have the path `clients/client_name`, and the same error with you. But if test with a container which has the path `clients/client_name`, then it deletes all the blobs inside it.

Otherwise, you should check cli version with `az --version`, the latest version is  **2.0.69**